# HttpResponseRedirect Reverse Args is returning the name of the View

Tags: python, django

I am a newb to django, so this is probably a simple error.   When i send view *list* the argument user_id from an identical HttpResponseRedirect from a different view (identical Redirect to the one in the view add). It works fine.

But when I click a submit button on the template and call the add view i get

*invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'add'*

Using the print function I saw that the proper ID int gets passed from *list* to the template, but somewhere between the template and recalling the *list* view it gets lost.  Then *add* passes the str "add" to the list view.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#views.py
def list(request, user_id): #list:list
    #...
    #...doing stuff
    #...
    context = RequestContext(request)

    #Gets Menus
    main = Menu.objects.get(pk=1) #pk 1 is the Main Menu made
    main_menu = main.food_item_set.all()

    mine = Menu.objects.get(pk=2) #pk 2 is the My Menu made
    print user_id
    p = Plan_User.objects.get(pk = int(user_id))
    id = p.id

    return render_to_response('foods_data/list.html', {'main_menu':main_menu, 
                              'user_id':id}, context)

def add(request): #list:add
    """Adds the selected item to My Menu."""
    if request.method == "POST":
        mine = Menu.objects.get(pk=2) #pk 2 is the My Menu made in getList.py
        f_name = request.POST.get("choice")
        user_number = request.POST.get("user_number")
        food_entry = Food_Item.objects.get(food_name=f_name)
        food_entry.menus.add(mine)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("list:list", args=(user_number,)))


 #list.html
{% for object in main_menu %}
<form id='main_list' method='post' action="{% url 'list:add' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="choice" value="{{ object.food_name }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_number" value="{{ user_id }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Add to Menu" name="selection"/>
    <label for="object{{ forloop.counter }}"></label></br>
</form>


#urls.py

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<user_id>.+)/$', views.list, name='list'),
    url(r'^add/$', views.add, name='add'),
    url(r'^remove/$', views.remove, name='remove'),
)
```

Comment: Couple of things - Do __not__ use `add` and `list` as function named. Also, move the URL pattern for `.+` to the end of the patterns

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to use `reverse`, passing in a *positional* argument, rather than a *keyword* argument. Notwithstanding other possible errors in your code, you should be able to reverse your URL using:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("list", args=(),
    kwargs={'user_id': user_number}))
```

As @karthikr mentioned, you'll want to re-arrange your URL patterns. Django tries to match patterns in top-down fashion, and your first URL pattern allows for any character `.` This will cause your first pattern to be matched regardless if the second and third patterns match or not.

Additionally you really want to make sure the value in the URL matches what you're expecting in the view, this this case, one or more sequential integers:

```
#urls.py

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^add/$', views.add, name='add'),
    url(r'^remove/$', views.remove, name='remove'),
    url(r'^(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', views.list, name='list'),
)
```